# Where am I archiving my documents too?

Tags: information-management, retention, information-policy

I set up a retention policy for a document library, so that 30 days after a document is uploaded or created it moves it to a storage folder. My question is, where is this storage folder?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, they go to the drop off folder.